# Setting up a private server for Windows and Mac Computers

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, mac

I work in a University Laboratory and we want to install a server that allows each user to login to any computer in the lab with their own credential (We have a small laboratory with about 10 computers). I understand that VMware allows for this to be done on Windows and Linux, but we also have Mac computers that we want to include in our network.

I don't have much experience in setting up this kind of network and we will probably hire someone to do it, but I would like to know what to ask for.

We want the following:

1) Every user in the lab (approximately 6 to 10 users in lab who will be using the computers) needs to be able to login to every computer in the lab with their own credentials. We want this to  be possible for both the Mac computers and the Windows computers (similar to how a university computer lab works).

2) We also want the main server to have storage for every user (We want to have ~20-30TB on this server computer setup in RAID). I haven't built the server that will house this yet because I want to know how to setup everything first.

3) We also use OneDrive from Microsoft as Online Cloud storage and would like to have it backed up on the server drive.

Is this possible? And if so, what kind of network I would need to setup and what would it require to get started?

Thanks

Comment: You need to hire someone now. Seriously, find a good systems administrator, and let them figure out how to get you what you want. Don't start down a path and then hire someone to fix it - that will be more work and headache than anyone wants to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OSX has Active Directory support.  [Here's](http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_integrating_active_directory_ml.pdf) a best practices document from Apple.  You should be able to use Active Directory to provide both logins and file shares.